# Pandas dataframe: summing cell data from a group of rows, storing in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As a part of a treatment for a health related issue, I need to measure my liquid intake (along with some other parameters), registring the amount of liquid every time I drink. I have a dataframe, of several months of such registration.
I want to sum my daily amount in an additional column (in red, image below)
As you may see, I wish like to store it in the first column of the slice returned by  `df.groupby(df['Date']).`, for all the days.

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby(df.Date).first()['Total']= df.groupby(df.Date)['Drank'].fillna(0).sum()
```

But seems not to be the way to do it.

Greatful for any advice.

Thanks
Michael

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- use fact `False==0`
- first row of date will be where **data** is not equal to `shift()` of date
- `merge()` to sum

```
## construct a data set
d = pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", "1-mar-2021", freq="2H")
A = np.random.randint(20,300,len(d)).astype(float)
A.ravel()[np.random.choice(A.size, A.size//2, replace=False)] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime":d, "Drank":A})

df = df.assign(Date=df.datetime.dt.date, Time=df.datetime.dt.time).drop(columns=["datetime"]).loc[:,["Date","Time","Drank"]]
## construction done

# first row will have different date to shift
# merge Total back
df.assign(row=df.Date.eq(df.Date.shift())).merge(df.groupby("Date", as_index=False).agg(Total=("Drank","sum")).assign(row=0), 
                                                 on=["Date","row"], how="left").drop(columns="row")
```